# Instaloader login or connection issue

Tags: python, connection, instagram

I'm trying connect to Instagram, but I can't. Where am I doing wrong?

```
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

L.login(username, password)
```

I'm getting this error, in this line

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: I've added username and password

Comment: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) means the json decoder was given an empty string . Check the input to make sure it has content

Comment: How should I give the inputs? I wrote like this: L.login('accountname','pass1234')

Comment: okay what version of instaloader are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 4.5.2